# Easiest way to replace illegal character in XML attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have a trouble with a hand-writting XML. The XML is generated by concat string as this :

```
            ReturnXML += "<agentchimique ";
            ReturnXML += "id_prod=\"" + Produit.Id + "\" ";
            ReturnXML += "nom_com_prod=\"" + Produit.NomComProd + "\" ";
            ReturnXML += "nom_four=\"" + Produit.Fournisseur.NomFour  + "\" ";
            ReturnXML += "PhraseR=\"" + Produit.PhrasesR.Replace( "<br/>", "@" ) + "\" ";
            ReturnXML += "PhraseS=\"" + Produit.PhrasesS.Replace( "<br/>", "@" ) + "\" ";
            ReturnXML += "numfds_prod=\"" + Produit.NumfdsProd.ToString() + "\" ";
            ReturnXML += "transverse_prod=\"" + Produit.TransverseProd.ToString() + "\" ";
```

This is only a few part of the whole XML and as you can see, all data is in attribute...
But some parameters as Produit.PhrasesR or Produit.PhrasesS can contains illegal character as < > or &.

This XML is stored as text in SQL and executed by SQL server, with the stored procedure sp_xml_preparedocument to be read in a report services.
This XML can be used too as data to generate as a webpage.

So, what is the quickest and easiest solution to resolve this encoding problem, as know I can not rewrite a true compliant XML (I don't have any time for this), and this XML is used on many place in my project (replace character would be the easiest but it demand to replace back in reports and webpage).

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [SecurityElement.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
ReturnXML += "nom_four=\"" + SecurityElement.Escape(Produit.Fournisseur.NomFour) + "\" ";
```

This will replace `<` with `&lt;`, `>` with `&gt;` etc.

Although you really should use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) to build your xml correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the SecurityElement.Escape, but I need to invert this when I read XML in Report services ? If it was me that would create XML, I'll use XDocument, but often I retrieve old project from lazy developper :)

Comment: @User.Anonymous I'm not sure. Maybe not. You'll have to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape them with their ASCII equivalents:

1. '<' must become '`&#60;`'
2. '>' must become '`&#62;`'
3. '&' must become '`&#38;`'

No shortcuts that I know of.

I don't think your issue is SQL.  Magic characters in XML make it ill-formed.  Is the XML you create valid?

Comment: the XML don't contains header, it is not W3C compliant. And the issue is in SQL sp with this error message : 6601:sp_xml_preparedocument:1: The XML parse error 0xc00ce506 occurred on line number 1, near the XML text. So I need a XML without data character error.